# ReportServiceException on Birt reports

Tags: birt

I have this problem in Birt, where in I try to generate a report, and when it is processing the report, I cancel the report and try to generate the same report again, I get ReportServiceException. However if I try to regenerate the report after some time the report generates fine. The time gap can be as much as 2 minutes at times.

I am attaching partial stack trace to this question. Can some one tell me a solution to this issue.

I am running Birt 2.5.2. I had upgraded it to 4.1.3 and tried to view the results, but the results were same.

```
org.eclipse.birt.report.service.api.ReportServiceException: Failed to open the report document.
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.ReportEngineService.throwDummyException(ReportEngineService.java:1096)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.ReportEngineService.openReportDocument(ReportEngineService.java:495)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.BirtViewerReportService.openReportDocument(BirtViewerReportService.java:269)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.BirtViewerReportService.getPageCount(BirtViewerReportService.java:704)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.actionhandler.AbstractGetPageActionHandler.prepareParameters(AbstractGetPageActionHandler.java:138)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.actionhandler.AbstractGetPageActionHandler.__execute(AbstractGetPageActionHandler.java:104)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.actionhandler.AbstractBaseActionHandler.execute(AbstractBaseActionHandler.java:90)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.soapengine.processor.AbstractBaseDocumentProcessor.__executeAction(AbstractBaseDocumentProcessor.java:47)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.soapengine.processor.AbstractBaseComponentProcessor.executeAction(AbstractBaseComponentProcessor.java:143)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of variables and I am not sure you provided sufficient detail to identify the problem.

**If you are using a SQL database**

The Query to the database may still be running and blocking your new attempt to connect.  Try setting the SQL Time Out.

- In the 'Property Editor' for the 'Data Set'
- On the 'Advanced' tab, expand the 'ODA Data Set'
- On '&Query Time Out (in seconds)' set a value (*I think 5 seconds is the minimum allowed*)

If this does not solve your problem.

If your SQL Query does not time out with a 5 second limit, than your query is running quick enough but something in your report creation, layout or deployment is the problem.  Provide additional details in your question, identifying the specific area you are having issues with.

Answer (score 0):

I found out the solution. In my case, the temporary file name for a report has a fixed value. Before generating a new report, the old temporary file has to be deleted.

The solution for the problem is to see that value for report parameter __document (This parameter sets the temporary file name) gets a new value every time. The best solution is to append the timestamp to the value in this report parameter every time. Please note that this will lead to lot of temp files being created every time a report is generated. Care has to be taken to see that the temporary files are deleted every now and then.